# How to make a radix is used on all parseInt() instances

Tags: javascript

The `parseInt() function can return undesired and/or unexpected results if the radix is not supplied.Please make  a radix is used on all parseInt() instances.

how to edit it

please helpme

i will send file if you need it

Comment: Show code please? What is the problem?

Comment: "*how to edit it*" - with a text editor?

Comment: jonathan . what is your mail iwill send it. more than one file

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398834/using-javascript-parseint-and-a-radix-parameter is related, if not a duplicate. If you don't understand it, please add a small example to your question and explain precisely what you don't know or understand. (No need to email complete source file around.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you **want** to create an *Error* when a *radix* is not passed,

1. Shadow `parseInt`, keeping the old reference in a closure such as an *IIFE*
2. Test for your conditions
3. Invoke the old reference

For example

```
parseInt = (function (old_parseInt) {
    return function parseInt(x, radix) {
        if (arguments.length < 2)
            throw new TypeError('parseInt must be given a radix');
        return old_parseInt.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}(parseInt));
```

Then in usage,

```
parseInt('12', 8); // 10
parseInt('12'); // TypeError: parseInt must be given a radix
```

---

*(Running this code on this page will break stackoverflow, be warned)*

Answer (score 0):

The radix is the second parameter to the parseInt() function.
It sets the numerical base that should be used when converting the string to an integer.

Obviously you would expect  `parseInt('11')` to always return 11 :)
This is not guaranteed by all various JavaScript implementations.

What is guaranteed though is that `parseInt('11', 10)` will always return that 11 that you'd expect "by instinct".

Choosing a different radix ( or working in an implementation that has a different default for that matter ) say 2 would mean that the number is interpreted relative to base 2 => `parseInt('11')` would actually mean `parseInt('11', 2)` and hence come out to 3.