# Im not getting the result what i want

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Actually im new to react redux and im buliding a project where i want to update a particular object in a array
I trying that but im not getting the desire result

```
const coinState = {
  coins: [],
};
export const coinReducer = (state = coinState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "AFTER_BUY": {
      return { ...state, coins: [...state.coins, action.payload] };
    }
    case "AFTER_SELL":
      return {
        ...state,
        coins: state.coins.filter(
          (c) => c.coinName !== action.payload.coinName
        ),
      };
    case "UPDATE_BUY": {
      const newArr = [...state.coins];
      newArr.map((coin) => {
        if (coin.id === action.payload.id) {
          Here i want to add previous and new state eg : coin.AmountofCoins=10 and
          payload coins is 10 then i want 20 as sum but
          getting 1010 as result
         
          coin.AmountOfCoins += action.payload.AmountOfCoins;

        }
      });
      return {
        coins: newArr,
      };
    }
```

Comment: please rename your question with real information.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems that one or both of your amounts are strings instead of integers.  Try using

```
coin.AmountOfCoins += parseInt(action.payload.AmountOfCoins, 10)
```

to coerce that to an integer.

Comment: parameters `10` is useless here

Comment: I prefer to always pass in a radix since we have no assurance what the first parameter will be.  Check [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10398851/6079412) for a little more info

Comment: @larz Tqq so much man